# AWS API fetch "Type Error: failed to fetch" but working for Postman and browser

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, postman

I am trying to make a call to an API endpoint on AWS Gateway which works totally fine in browser and postman, but in my code it is failing with:

> "Type Error: failed to fetch".

What is the likely cause of this?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your code and not with the API. You should post the code and if possible the full error message (including stacktrace). Have you checked if you authenticated properly etc. It might be that you are not getting back JSON but some other message that can't be decoded to JSON. Add as much information as possible. Otherwise, it will be very hard to help you.

Comment: switched from using fetch to using axios and it's working fine now.  not sure what the issue is, nothing else changed.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled almost hours Fetch and PUT request. via the Postman the gateway accepts and programmatic it fails. I tried re-configuring CORS on the API gate way to allow all kind of access. it worked !